# How to print chinese character using printDocument in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, character-encoding, printdocument

I want to print chinese character (or other encoding character sets) using:

```
void printDocument_1PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   e.Graphics.DrawString("人", new Font("MingLiU Regular", 14), Brushes.Black, new Point(x, y), StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
}
```

I have already file.txt which contains encoding text, and I can open it using notepad or notepad++ with special font family MingLiU Regular in my Fonts Collection,
thanks before